# Xamarin.Forms bind Height of Grid to Width of Button

Tags: xaml, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I try to build the following UI Element with `Xamarin.Forms`. I was able to build this with `UWP` by binding the `Height` property of the `TopGrid` to the `ActualWidth` property of `Button1`. However this is not working in Xamarin.Forms, because there is no `ActualWidth` property. I already tried binding the `Height` of `TopGrid` to `WidthRequest`, but without success.

[image]

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="TopGrid" Grid.Row="0" BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=Button1}"  Height="{Binding Path=WidthRequest}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="Button1" Grid.Column="0" Text="1" />
        <Button x:Name="Button2" Grid.Column="1" Text="2" />
        <Button x:Name="Button3" Grid.Column="2" Text="3" />
        <Button x:Name="Button4" Grid.Column="3" Text="4" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Does anybody have experience with `Xamarin.Forms` and can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First thing first: Xaml names are case-sensitive, so instead of

```xml
BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=button1}"
```

this should be

```xml
BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=Button1}"
```

Beside this, your Xaml was almost ok. Let's look at

```xml
Height="{Binding Path=WidthRequest}"
```

You're trying to bind to the view's height, but the `HeightProperty` is a read-only BindableProperty, so you can't set it. If you look at the API, there's no public setter for the `Height` property either. So, instead of binding to the Height, you should bind to the HeightRequest.

```xml
HeightRequest="{Binding Path=WidthRequest}"
```

That's the way of saying that you'd like the `Grid` to be of that height, and the layout system will do its best to make you happy (but that's a best effort only).

I think you get this by now. The button `WidthRequest` is the request made by the user, and in this case, it's not set and it's value is left to the default. Instead, you want to use the button's actual `Width` as source property of your binding. Let's do it:

```xml
HeightRequest="{Binding Width}"
```

and this gives the expected result:

[image: actual result]

Here's the full corrected Xaml snippet:

```xml
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid x:Name="TopGrid" Grid.Row="0" BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=Button1}"  HeightRequest="{Binding Width}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="Button1" Grid.Column="0" Text="1" BackgroundColor="Pink"/>
    <Button x:Name="Button2" Grid.Column="1" Text="2" BackgroundColor="Pink"/>
    <Button x:Name="Button3" Grid.Column="2" Text="3" BackgroundColor="Pink"/>
    <Button x:Name="Button4" Grid.Column="3" Text="4" BackgroundColor="Pink"/>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to set the BindingContext for the whole grid (and every item in it), then you can just specify it directly in the binding as follows, allowing all other controls to retain their original BindingContext:

```
 <Grid x:Name="TopGrid" Grid.Row="0" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference Button1}}">
```