# Button/label inside grid gets incorrect height (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, controls

I have two buttons inside a grid, one of them containing a longer text which does not fit on one line. The button with the long text seems to get an incorrect height and some of the text is invisible. From what I can see, the height is the one it would have needed if it was using the full width of the screen (comparison with a button outside the grid). Labels seem to behave in a similar manner.

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="1 line" />
        <Button Text="Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4 Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8 Word9 Word10 Word11 Word12 Word13 Word14 Word15 Word16 Word17 Word18 Word19 Word20" />
        <Grid BackgroundColor="Cyan">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="1 line" />
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4 Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8 Word9 Word10 Word11 Word12 Word13 Word14 Word15 Word16 Word17 Word18 Word19 Word20" />

            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Green" Text="1 line" />
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Magenta" Text="Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4 Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8 Word9 Word10 Word11 Word12 Word13 Word14 Word15 Word16 Word17 Word18 Word19 Word20" />
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

And here is the result:

[image: Elements inside the grid get incorrect height]

Am I missing something in the grid definition to make the elements in it be measured correctly?

Comment: You can bind the button height to the grid height. Here is the link you can refer to [Label and grid auto height and width adjust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008289/xamarin-forms-bind-height-of-grid-to-width-of-button).

Comment: I don’t need square buttons, I need auto height of the buttons which then defines also the height of the grid. So the height of all elements shall be computed based on their content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding Button inside StackLayout

```
<StackLayout>
    <Button Text="1 line" />
    <Button Text="Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4 Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8 Word9 Word10 Word11 Word12 Word13 Word14 Word15 Word16 Word17 Word18 Word19 Word20" />
    <Grid x:Name="grid" BackgroundColor="Cyan">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Button x:Name="btn1"  Text="1 line" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
            <Button x:Name="btn2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4 Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8 Word9 Word10 Word11 Word12 Word13 Word14 Word15 Word16 Word17 Word18 Word19 Word20 Word21 Word22 Word23 Word24" SizeChanged="btn2_SizeChanged" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Green" Text="1 line" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Magenta" Text="Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4 Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8 Word9 Word10 Word11 Word12 Word13 Word14 Word15 Word16 Word17 Word18 Word19 Word20" />
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

And in code-behind

```
private void btn2_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grid.RowDefinitions[0].Height = (sender as Button).Height;
}
```

[image]

**Note : You can do same for the Label in second row**

Comment: Using this method I was able to fix the issue in a FlexLayout as well (which acts the exact same way as a single row grid). I still don't understand the underlying problem (or is it a bug?) but this is a feasible workaround.